# JW Player mouse click position

Tags: jwplayer

I can't get mouse click position from event data

```
jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function(event)
{
alert(event.pageX+" "+event.offsetX+" "+event.clientX);
```

All 3 values displayed as undefined.

Do you know how to get mouse click position? May be another way?

Need to get mouse position x,y when user click by video.

Thank you!

Comment: I am fairly certain that the onDisplayClick function does not report that information. You might need to get the offsetX for the actual jwplayer div using document.getElementById for example, instead.